# Perl one-liner that combines two if statements into one

Tags: perl

I have written a perl code in a script format. Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

    while(<>){
        chomp;
        my @s = split /\t/,$_;
        if($_ =~ /NM:i:(\d+) and $1 >= 7/){
            print $_,"\n";
        }
    }
```

I want to write this perl script.pl code in perl one liner fashion. Itried something like this, but it is failing to do what I expect it to do:

```
perl -ne '@s = split; if $_ =~ /NM:i:(\d+)/{ print if $1 >=7}'
```

How to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: What it is the purpose of `@s` ? It is not used for anything

Comment: Try this `perl -ne 'print if /NM:i:(\d+)/ and $1 >=7' file.txt`

Comment: Yea I agree, I just used it to split the lines into columns, but you are right, no use of it here.

Comment: your solution works, but does that mean in my script.pl, I can avoid 2 if statements?

Comment: you have to use one if statement in your script also

Answer (score 3):

```sh
perl -ne'print if /NM:i:(\d+)/ && $1 >= 7'
```

---

You have a needless split on tab in there. But let's say you actually needed it. If so, you could use

```sh
perl -F'\t' -lane'print if $F[0] =~ /NM:i:(\d+)/ && $1 >= 7'
```

This only matches against the first field.

---

> *does that mean in my script.pl, I can avoid 2 if statements?*

Yes.

Aside from scoping differences, the following are equivalent:

```perl
if (f()) {
   if (g()) {
      h();
   }
}

if (f() && g()) {
   h();
}

h() if f() && g();

f() && g()
   and h();
```

Comment: Thanks, I also want to print lines that begin with @ and once they are printed move on to the next line and perform the one liner above. How can I print the lines beginning with @

Comment: You can check if the string in `$_` start with `@` using `/^\@/`.

Comment: `perl -ne 'print if /^\@/ ; print if /NM:i:(\d+)/ and $1 >=7'`

Comment: That could print some lines twice.

Comment: I guess those lines would be the once that matches /^\@/ and are also checked for `if /NM:i:(\d+)/ and $1 >=7` condition

Comment: yes. Consider the difference between "Print the line if it's of type A. Print the line if it's of type B." and "Print the line if it's of type A or B."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239964/discussion-between-user3138373-and-ikegami).

Answer (score 2):

I tend to think about these problems as the lines to skip rather than the lines to output. But, the combination of the conditions is the same as what [ikegami has already shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70281649/2766176):

```
perl -pe 'next unless(/NM:i:(\d+)/ && $1 >= 7)' ...
```